# Find Product Id and Vendor Id of USB_FlashDrive using Java

Tags: java, vbscript

I need help to find the product and vendor ID of USB_Flash-drive, I used the following code but it won't work,

```
public static String getProductId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String result = "";
        try {
            File file = File.createTempFile("realhowto", ".vbs");
            file.deleteOnExit();
            FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(file);

            String vbs = "Set objWMIService = GetObject(\"winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2\")\n"
                    + "Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ \n"
                    + "   (\"Select * from Win32_USBHub WHERE\"\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0\"\") \n"
                    + "For Each objItem in colItems \n"
                    + "    Wscript.Echo objItem.PNPDeviceID \n"
                    + "    exit for  ' do the first cpu only! \n" + "Next \n";
            fw.write(vbs);
            fw.close();
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result.trim();
    }
```

In this above code i use this line `(\"Select * from Win32_USBHub\") \n"` instead of `(\"Select * from Win32_USBHub WHERE\"\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0\"\") \n"`, which give the Product and Vendor id of my Dvd_Drive. Here what should i do for the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Win32_USBController

http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/disk/drives/#RetrUBSHubInfo.htm

Comment: i already used this, but i want only Pid and Vid, of my pen-drive only